# Why does my int not print

Tags: c#, console

I'm new to coding Blah Blah same old story but I put this code in:

```
{
    public static Random Random;

    public int numberOne = 5;
    public int numberTwo = 6;


    public void Run()
    {
        numberOne = Random.Next(0,11);
        numberTwo = Random.Next(0,6);

        Console.WriteLine(numberOne +" + "+ numberTwo);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

`numberOne` and `numberTwo` are both public `int`'s. Why doesnt this work?

it comes back with an error stating that

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."

What does that mean?

Comment: Where is `Random` defined? There is a `Random` class but it is not static. Did you forget to initialize that property?

Comment: Yeah my bad, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use my *crystal ball*: in the code in the question - since `numberOne` and `numberTwo` are `int` - the main possibility to have

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

is the fragment like this:

```
// just a declaration without initialization
public static Random Random; // <- the instance doesn't created

...

{
// Addressing Random which is null cause NullReferenceException 
numberOne = Random.Next(0,11);
numberTwo = Random.Next(0,6);

Console.WriteLine(numberOne +" + "+ numberTwo);
Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Remedy: initialize the field with created `Random` instance

```
// Now Random is initialized
private static Random Random = new Random();
```

Comment: ugh my bad you right, it works now thanks :) i miss read what i wrote

Comment: @deviousPriest: you've just *declared*, but haven't *initialized* `Random` field with any `Random` inistance.